# I cant create a back button for my tkinter gui

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I want to create a tkinter window with different pages, and a go back button nside every window. I dont want to create a seperate frame on main window for pages instead I want to create a totally new window with different button setting in every window but the go back button is a must.

I have tried creating a window and to get back I have to destroy that window, But the problem is that when the go back button is pressed the window is destroyed, and when I want to go to that page again, I can not go there. There are not any pointers in python. I think I am messing up OOP.

```
import tkinter as tk


def create_pages(base):
    global p1


    p1 = Page1(base)
    p1.lift()
    print('test')


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def show(self):
        self.lift()


class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        b7 = tk.Button(self, text="Main Menu", command=self.on_cancel)
        b7.pack(side="left")


    def on_cancel(self):
        self.destroy()





class MainView(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.p1 = Page1(self)

        container = tk.Frame(self)



        self.p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


        label = tk.Label(container, text="This is Mainvuiew")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        b1 = tk.Button(container, text="Page 1", command=  lambda: MainView.printing(self))


        b1.pack(side="left")




        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.p1.show()

    def printing( self):
        self.p1=Page1(self)

        self.p1.lift()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

I just want pages with go back button to the main menu and not a seperate frame for button that keeps on displaying on every page.

Comment: if you destroyed window then you have to create it again. Or better don't destroy because if you destroy it then you destroy also useful information which you may have in Entry, Text, etc. in this window.

Comment: That is the problem, I am struglling in creating it again. I have created a function in Class MainView to create it agian. But not working.

Comment: Infact, I am not able to create class using a function inside class. That sums it.

Comment: every class has access to its parent and it should run function which is in parent, and this function should recreate Page.

Comment: Try changing all `container` to `self.container` and add `self.p1.place(...)` after initializing `Page1(...)` inside `printing()` function.

Comment: Thanks furas, solved my problem.